# unable to loop and add the second value for an array

Tags: c#

In a below loop i would like to add the second value of sr by separating with "," only if the there are more than one value. else it has to display sr value with out ",".

```
                var size = 0;
                if (records != null)
                {
                    size = records.Length;
                }
                var srArray = new List<SRItem>();
                var i = 0;
                if (records == null) return Json(srArray);
                foreach (var item in records)
                {
                    foreach (var prr in item.Psr)
                    {
                        srArray.Add(new SRItem
                        {
                            name = pr.Name.lastName + "/" + pr.Name.firstName,
                            st= pr.Seat.seatNumber,
                            sr = pr.PSRList[0].SRCode                                
                        });

                    }
                    i++;
                }


                return Json(srArray.ToArray());
            }
            else
            {
                throw new Exception("Session no longer exists, Please refresh the whole page");
            }
```

Comment: I am unable to loop pr.PSRList value based on their coount.

Comment: Is that supposed to be "pr" or "prr"?  If you are not able to loop based on count of pr.PSRList's items, can you at least loop using "foreach"?  If you can do a "foreach" loop, then you can find out whether or not it has more than one items in it.

Comment: I don't see where you attempt to loop it. What exactly is the problem?

Comment: Agreed, there is no code there showing any attempt to iterate over `pr.PSRList`, only a single assignment that grabs the first item's `SRCode`.

Comment: Also the fact that you abbreviated everything makes your code hard to read, shorter code is not better code'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood your description correct you want something like

```
sr = string.Join(", ", pr.PSRList.Select(p => p.SRCode));
```

Answer (score 0):

What is the purpose of var i?

also you're creating prr and trying to access them in the loop with pr. change prr to pr or pr to prr.

```
foreach (var prr in item.Psr) //< ---prr
{
    //in here you have pr
    srArray.Add(new SRItem
    {
        name = pr.Name.lastName + "/" + pr.Name.firstName,
        st= pr.Seat.seatNumber,
        sr = pr.PSRList[0].SRCode                                
    });
}
```

change to:

```
foreach (var pr in item.Psr)
{
    srArray.Add(new SRItem
    {
        name = pr.Name.lastName + "/" + pr.Name.firstName,
        st= pr.Seat.seatNumber,
        sr = pr.PSRList[0].SRCode                                
    });
}
```